# where to call the Axios post request in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios, use-effect

I have a form,thats data are saved in the state to be sent to the backend server.
i am handling the form with handleSubmit function and useEffect hook, where the handleSubmit prevents the form from being submitted unless it calls the validation function, in the useEffect I check if there are any errors using if condition and then console.log my data.
now I want to post the data hold in the state -the state is sent as a props to me- but I am confused whether to put the request in the HandleSubmit function or in the useEffect inside the body of the if condition.

```
import react, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


import './sign.css';

const SignA = (props) => {

    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmit, setIsSubmit] = useState(false);


    const handleSubmit = (err) => {
        err.preventDefault();
        setFormErrors(validate(props.data));
        setIsSubmit(true);
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(Object.keys(formErrors).length);
        if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0 && isSubmit) {
            console.log('console the props data', props.data)
//here is where I think the post request should be put
            if (isSubmit) {
                return (navigate('/profileadmin'))
            }

        }
    }, [formErrors])

    const validate = (values) => {
        const errors = {};
        const regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/i;

        if (!values.firstname) {
            errors.firstname = 'firstname is required!';
        }
        if (!values.lastname) {
            errors.lastname = 'lastname is required!';
        }
        if (!values.mobile) {
            errors.mobile = 'mobile is required!';
        }
        if (!values.email) {
            errors.email = 'email is required!';
        } else if (!regex.test(values.email)) {
            errors.email = 'this is not a valid email format!'
        }
        return errors;
    }

   

    return (

        <div className='signup'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <div className="name">
                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="First name"
                                name="firstname"
                                id='firstName'
                                value={props.data.firstname}
                                onChange={props.change}
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Last name"
                                name="lastname"
                                value={props.data.lastname}
                                onChange={props.change}
                            />
                        </div>



                    </div>
                    <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.firstname}</p>
                    <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.lastname}</p>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Business mobile number"
                            name="mobile"
                            value={props.data.mobile}
                            onChange={props.change}
                        />
                        <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.mobile}</p>
                        <br />
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Email Adress"
                            name="email"
                            value={props.data.email}
                            onChange={props.change}
                        />
                        <p className='errorMsg'>{formErrors.email}</p>
                        <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div className="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" className="check" />i’ve read and agree with <a href="url" >Terms of service</a>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="clearfix">
                        <button type="submit" className="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form >
        </div >
    )
}




export default SignA;
```

this is the request

```
 axios.post('', props.data)
                .then(res => console.log('post res', res))
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('There was an error in post request!', error);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need useEffect here.

Here is how you can implement such thing:

Declare a state to hold form values:

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({})
```

Declare function to set the state:

```
const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setFormData({...formData, [name]: value})
}
```

Input onChange to capture:

```
// handleChange has two parameters
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="First name"
    name="firstname"
    id='firstName'
    value={props.data.firstname}
    onChange={(event) => handleChange('firstName', event.target.value)}
/>
```

function for calling post axios post request

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    //check for validations code here

    // if validations are right then post request here
    // this will give you all the fields like firstName: "", lastName: ""
    let requestBody = {
        ...formData
    }
    axios.post("url", requestBody).then((res)=> {
        //your code here
    })
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering me, I want to notify you that handlechange and state are passed as props from a parent component to this component.  also, I want to make sure I got your idea right, Do you mean I can do the if condition for checking on errors inside the handlesubmit function?

Comment: You can use onBlur={validate} in the input tag. That should work :)

Comment: okay, it does work. but would it be wrong if I used the useEffect and put the post request in it ?

Comment: useEffect is basically used for handling side-effects. You dont need when using POST request because you are sending the data. useEffect is the perfect candidate for calling GET requests.